# Impossible definite integral!

Tags: definite-integrals

Is it possible to calculate this integral?

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-a\sqrt{b^2+x^2}\right)\sin(cx)\frac{dx}{x}$$

I'm tired of it. I almost used any method to calculate this definite integral. It seems there is no analytic solution. I need help. Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. While being tired of it, could you please update your question using [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)? Also, please improve the title. Finally, please show some effort/discuss what is the problem/difficulty, or at least give some context.

Comment: Are you sure that the sine should be in the exponential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not converging. If $c\neq 0$, we have divergence on a neighbourhood of $\frac{3\pi}{2|c|}+\frac{2\pi}{|c|}\mathbb{Z}$.

If $c=0$, we have a non-integrable singularity in the origin.

Comment: Before it was mathjax'd I read it as if the sine was outside the exponential function (now I checked, and it was not). After all, the title of the question was not bad...